# Assigning variables to Strings

Tags: c++, string, struct

I am a beginner at learning structures. There is a bit of a problem with my code. I know this isn't the way to assign strings. Could someone please show me how to? The website taught me to do it like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PERSON 50
#define NAME_LENGTH 30
#define ADDR_LENGTH 60

struct player {

    char name [NAME_LENGTH];
    char address [ADDR_LENGTH];     
    int salary;

};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

   struct player singleTeams;
   struct player multipleTeams[MAX_PERSON];

   singleTeams.name = "David";
   multipleTeams[20].name = "Robin";

   printf("Person on the single team is %s\n", singleTeams.name);
   printf("Person on the multiple team is %s\n", multipleTeams[20].name);


   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My error is on this line

```
   singleTeams.name = "David";
   multipleTeams[20].name = "Robin";
```

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: what you want is [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/)

Long answer: In defining name as a character array in a struct, you are allocating a set amount of memory in that struct to store the characters in the name. To move characters into that space, you have to copy them, and that's where `strncpy` comes in.

You could also have defined `name` as a pointer to char (`char *`), in which case your assignments would make sense. In C, when you use a literal string, you're really including those bytes somewhere within your executable, and that `"..."` syntax returns the pointer to where those characters are statically stored, as a `char *`. From a type standpoint, `char *` is a less specific type than `char[30]`, and so you cannot directly assign that pointer into your `player.name` variable. From a C implementation standpoint, `name` is not actually a writable pointer variable in the sense that it contains a mutable value; it simply represents a specific part of the memory of the struct (namely the first byte of a 30 byte buffer), and cannot be reassigned to point at the "David" or "Robin" constants instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the C++ defined **string** like that.This is how you do it.

```
 struct player {
   std::string name;
   std::string address;     
   int salary;
 };
```

Strings are pretty handy character arrays which are dynamic, which means you don't need to specify the size at compile time.It automatically re-sizes.Also you have a ton of functions defined in the string library that will make life easy for you.

Read up on strings [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Comment: As you can see the person has tagged the question in C++.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this function

```
strcpy(singleTeams.name, "David")
```

or use string in C++.